# How to test service in Nestjs?

Tags: typescript, axios, ts-jest, nestjs-testing

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class FileUploadService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(FileUploadService.name);

  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}
}
```

spec.ts

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [FileUploadService],
    }).compile();

    fileService = app.get<FileUploadService>(FileUploadService);
  });
```

error
[Test Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO0K9.png)

Who can help me?
I tried all of stackoverflow and still couldn't solve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createMock } from '@golevelup/ts-jest'

const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [
    MainService
  ]
})
.useMocker(() => createMock())
.compile()
```

It help me to run test successfully.

But I don't know if it's right？？？